# laravel : Pass information with key in url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Hello i want to make url like `example.com/overview-schedule?=user_key=123456` in laravel. I do not know how to do it.

Sharing my code :
In blade.php define a link

```
 <a href="{{ route("overview-schedule") }}">
```

on my web.php

```
Route::any('overview-schedule', 'Front\PlanController@scheduleOverview')->name('overview-schedule');
```

Got an error

> InvalidArgumentException
>   Route [overview-schedule?user_key=123456] not defined.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `url()` helper method

```
$user_key = 123456;
<a href="{{ url('/overview-schedule?user_key='.$user_key) }}">
```

Comment: how can i gt user_key on a function?

Comment: how you get `123456`?? i just assign it to a variable

Comment: `return redirect('overview-schedule/?user_key='.$UserUniqueCode)->with('success', trans('msg'));` so on the overview-schedule i want to gt user_key like in core php $_REQUEST['user_key']

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of parameters to route function :

```
 <a href="{{ route("overview-schedule" , ['user_key' => $user_key]) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<a href="{{ url('/overview-schedule?user_key='.$user_key) }}">
```